# PolarProxy doesnt write packets to the pcap file

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, ssl, tls

Im trying to use PolarProxy on windows to capture some packets but when i test it out it doesnt write anything to the pcap file

I tried using --autoflush 1 which is meant to write it to pcap file everyone second but it didnt do anything

The command im using: PolarProxy -p 10443,80,3129 --connect 10.0.2.25 --leafcert sign -w decrypted.pcap --autoflush 1

Comment: Just out of curiosity - did you install WinPCap on your Windows computer?

Comment: yea i did install it

Answer (score 0):

The `-p 10443,80,3129 --connect 10.0.2.25` PolarProxy arguments are designed to be used in a setup where there is a traditional proxy (such as squid) listening on TCP port 3129 at 10.0.2.25. Here’s the documentation for that mode of operation from the [PolarProxy website](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy):

> Transparent In-Line Proxy : PolarProxy decrypts, re-encrypts and
> forwards all TLS connections to a specific proxy, security gateway or
> some other form of “Next-Generation Firewall”. Use the --connect
> argument to specify which server to connect to.

If this is what you want to do, then the next obstacle is to get the Windows machine to redirect outgoing packets to the local TCP port 10443, which PolarProxy is listening to. You can verify that PolarProxy is listening to this port by making a connection with curl like this:

```
curl --insecure --connect-to www.netresec.com:443:127.0.0.1:10443 https://www.netresec.com/
```

You might also wanna start PolarProxy with the `-v` argument to get more detailed output to the console.

However, the Windows firewall is unfortunately quite terrible when it comes to redirecting outgoing traffic. You will most likely have more success if you configure PolarProxy to run as a SOCKS proxy (using `--socks 1080`) or HTTP Proxy (with `--httpconnect 8080`)  and configure your browser to connect to that proxy. Another alternative is to use a custom tool to redirect outgoing traffic from the Windows machine to PolarProxy as described in the [PolarProxy in Windows Sandbox](https://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2022-01&post=PolarProxy-in-Windows-Sandbox) blog post.